# Django template internationalization - non-Roman (Greek)

Tags: python, django, templates, unicode, internationalization

I'm having an issue with Django, and title-casing non-Roman strings in templates.  From what I've read, there can be similar issues around apostrophes, but in this case, it's accented characters.

Currently, the basics of my code looks like this:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load static %} 
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
    {% language 'el' %}
        {% for sub_dir in sub_dirs %}
            {{sub_dir.name |title}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endlanguage %}
{% endblock %}
```

The source in the variable is:
    μουσικές και σκοποί του πόντου

The result I get is:
    ΜουσικέΣ Και Σκοποί Του ΠόΝτου

The result that I want, is:
    Μουσικές Και Σκοποί Του Πόντου

The English that's intermixed, presents fine.  In this case, I know that there's only one other potential language involved, so I tried specifying it, which isn't making a difference.  I also wonder what happens in the case of multiple non-Roman/Latin scripts, but one issue at a time.

For the language code, according to various charts, I've tried 'el', 'el-gr', 'el-GR', and 'gr'

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks